# Matlab Compiler: issues compiling code that includes a pre-trained neural netowork

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-compiler, pre-trained-model

I have a Matlab script that I want to compile in a standalone executable using Matlab Compiler. The code loads a couple of pre-trained networks that I have tailored on my problem, starting from Inceptionv3. The code runs OK before compilation, but when I run the compiled app, I've got an error as if it was not possible to load the pre-trained networks (.mat files).

I've searched on the web and on the official documentation, but there is a lack of clear response on this. I made myself sure that the problem is not due to the relative/absolute path. 
There are suggestions on the web regarding the use of the command "%#function", but, by reading the documentation, it seems not to be what I need.

Here is when I load the models:

% load pre-trained network
model1 = load(fullfile(model_abspath,'Inceptionv3_net1.mat'));
model2 = load(fullfile(model_abspath,'Inceptionv3_net2.mat'));

net1 = model1.Inceptionv3_net1;
net2 = model2.Inceptionv3_net2;

---

Later on, in the code, I classify images using, for example:

[YPred,probs] = classify(model1.Inceptionv3_net1,img);

This is the error I got, and it happens when I try to load the models:

"Warning: Unable to load instances of class nnet.inceptionv3.layer.ScalingLayer into a heterogeneous array.  The definition of nnet.inceptionv3.layer.ScalingLayer could be missing or contain an error.  Default objects will be substituted.
Warning: While loading an object of class 'DAGNetwork':
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."